# Coding Assessment App: How to have a running a console with output in Angular app

Tags: angular

I'm looking at building a 'Coding assesment app' for an angular project and I'm having trouble researching.

The idea is to have consoles on the page where users can try and run their code and view an output, something along the lines of W3schools Try it! option (https://www.w3schools.com/js/tryit.asp?filename=tryjs_statements)

I'm trying to find out how I would go about doing this?

Problem is that anything a search with the words 'angular' and 'console' shows me how to use the angular CLI :')

**Any input would be appreciated!**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the search "angular code editor library".
I found this library, she seems to do the job : https://github.com/ngstack/code-editor